# How to redirect to specific page based on form input with JS?

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect

I'm new to javascript and this is probably really simple and obvious, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I want a specific form response to send the user to a specific page, for example, typing "one" and hitting enter would take them to the page "/one.html" if that makes sense? Any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.location = document.getElementById('yourinputfield').value() + '.html';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what context to put that in? If I have 4 pages to choose from, do I put that in if statement format? If so, how? I'm seriously a beginning beginner, I'm clueless! D:

Comment: you'd put it into an onsubmit, or onchange in your form. if you want to restrict where the users can choose to go, then don't let them type in anything. just give them a dropdown or checkboxes or whatever and work from there.